# How to add subdomain pointing to other website on same server

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain

I have 2 websites I want to run on one virtual machine.
One is a NodeJS server, the other an Nginx server.

The main website `website.example` points to the NodeJS server.
Now I want a subdomain like  `shop.website.example` to point to the Nginx server.

The virtual machine is in Azure.

I've read that it's not possible to link a subdomain to a specific port, so that's already not possible.

Would it be possible to have different IP's that go to the website, and would route to the right server based on the IP that is being used?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you want to access the two websites in the same Azure VM, It's possible to use two DNS records to map to your Azure VM.

First of all, the two websites should listen on different ports. Then you can use `A` record to map the domain name `website.example` to the Azure VM public IP address. A `CNAME` record maps the subdomain name `shop.website.example` to the [Azure VM FQDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn#create-a-fqdn). You should bind the different hostname of the websites with different ports on the Azure VM.

Also, make sure you could access the website outside of Azure. You could check the NSG rule or local firewall or website is listening for 0.0.0.0 on the Azure VM.